# How can I write two words as a single string(ex:- Course Name) in React.js to render a file>

Tags: reactjs

I Basically want to import a file from API that has the string name as "Course Name" and due to the space I am unable to render it.

const CardList = ({ courses }) => {
      return (
        
             {courses.map((course, i) => {
            return ();
            })
          }
        
      );
}

Comment: concatenate `Course + Name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spaces aren't allowed in attribute names, see here: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html. You can still access objects with keys that have spaces in them like this:

```
    <div>
        ...
        courseName = {courses[i]['Course Name']}
        ...
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

App.js

```
  CardList = ({courses}) => courses.map(item => <Courses key={item.id} course={item}/>);
```

Create component Courses.

```
 import React from 'react';

    const Courses = (props) =>
      <div className="CourseName">
        <p><i>Course Name: </i> {props.course}</p>       
        <hr/>
      </div>;

    export default Courses ;
```